# "server" directive is not allowed here in /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/conf.d/, what i did wrong here ? (0 Replies, Read 16 times)

Tags: nginx

i got this Error :

```
"server" directive is not allowed here in /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/conf.d/mydomain.com.conf:1 
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/nginx.conf test failed
```

i use with **Webuzo control panel + Lemp Stack** from there .
this what i did... 
i configured **nginx.conf** to this settings:

```
 #user  www-data;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid     /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {

    # Let NGINX get the real client IP for its access logs
    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For; 


    # Basic Settings
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 20;
    client_max_body_size 15m;
    client_body_timeout 60;
    client_header_timeout 60;
    client_body_buffer_size  1K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;
    send_timeout 60;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # Logging Settings
    error_log /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/error_log debug;
    access_log /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/web.access.log;

    # Log Format
        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    # Gzip Settings
    gzip on;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 512;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component 
    application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json 
    application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf 
    font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml;

    include /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

and after that i checked with **nginx -t** and it was ok...

I continued to the next file **mydomain.com.conf** and this what i putted there:

```
server { 
    listen       127.0.0.1:8080; 
    server_name  mydomain.com; 

    port_in_redirect off; 
    server_tokens off; 
    autoindex off; 

    client_max_body_size 15m; 
    client_body_buffer_size 128k; 

    access_log  /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/mydomain.com.log main; 
    error_log   /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/mydomain.com.err; 

    root   /home/www-data/public_html; 
    index index.php  index.html index.htm; 
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php; 

    error_page  404              /404.html; 
    location = /404.html { 
        root   /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc//html; 
    } 

    # Define default caching of 24h 
    expires 86400s; 
    add_header Pragma public; 
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"; 

    # Redirect server error pages to static 50x.html 
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html; 
    location = /50x.html { 
        root   /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc//html; 
    } 

    # Don't log robots.txt requests 
    location = /robots.txt { 
        allow all; 
        log_not_found off; 
        access_log off; 
    } 

    # Rewrite for versioned CSS+JS via filemtime 
    location ~* ^.+.(css|js) { 
        rewrite ^(.+).(d+).(css|js)$ $1.$3 last; 
        expires 31536000s; 
        access_log off; 
        log_not_found off; 
        add_header Pragma public; 
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"; 
    } 

    # Aggressive caching for static files 
    # If you alter static files often, please use 
    # add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"; 
    location ~* .(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg$ 
        expires 31536000s; 
        access_log off; 
        log_not_found off; 
        add_header Pragma public; 
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"; 
    } 

    location ~* (^(?!(?:(?!(php|inc)).)*/uploads/).*?(php)) { 
        try_files $uri = 404; 
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$; 
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket; 
        fastcgi_index index.php; 
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name; 
        include /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/fastcgi_params; 
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on; 
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off; 
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60; 
        fastcgi_send_timeout 180; 
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180; 
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k; 
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k; 
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k; 
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k; 
    } 

}
```

and **WebuzoVH.conf**
code:

```html
# DO NOT EDIT. AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED BY WEBUZO.

server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     mydomain.com www.my domain.com;
        # The Document Root
        root            /home/www-data/public_html;
        error_log       /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/mydomain.com.err;
        access_log      /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/mydomain.com.log main;
        include         /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/conf.d/common;
}
```

what wrong here , how can I fix that ?

i sit on that almost 5 hours  :-(

thanks for all who can help me, 
Tomer.

Comment: What does *"(0 Replies, Read 16 times)"* refer to in your title?

Comment: Did you use a http context and put server block inside that? like http { ... server }

Comment: I FORGOT TO ADD THE content of Nginx.conf                                                       but now it's show...                                                             so if you can see again i appreciate that thanks..

Comment: Do you have other `*.conf` files in that directory?

Comment: yes, i have WebuzoVH.conf that came with the Control Panel Webuzo:                    Code:                                                                     
# DO NOT EDIT. AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED BY WEBUZO.

server {
        listen          80;
        server_name     mydomain.com www.my domain.com;
        # The Document Root
        root            /home/www-data/public_html;
        error_log       /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/mydomain.com.err;
        access_log      /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/mydomain.com.log main;
        include         /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/conf.d/common;
}

Answer (score 0):

i change to this setting and now Nginx give **OK** in Command
this what i changed..
maybe this can be help to other..

the **nginx.conf** file

```html
#user  www-data;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid  /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/nginx.pid;

events {
 worker_connections  1024;
        multi_accept on;
        use epoll;
}


http {

    # Let NGINX get the real client IP for its access logs
    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For; 

    # Basic Settings
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 20;
    client_max_body_size 15m;
    client_body_timeout 60;
    client_header_timeout 60;
    client_body_buffer_size  1K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    large_client_header_buffers 4 8k;
    send_timeout 60;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;
   
    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;
 
    include /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    
    # Logging Settings
    #access_log /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/web.access.log;
    error_log /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/error_log debug;

    # Log Format
    log_format main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    # Gzip Settings
    gzip on;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_min_length 512;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/css text/javascript text/xml text/plain text/x-component 
    application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json 
    application/xml  application/rss+xml font/truetype application/x-font-ttf 
    font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject image/svg+xml

    include /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/sites-enabled/*;   
}
```

and this for **Mydomain.com.conf** file

```html
server {
    listen       127.0.0.1:8080;
    server_name  mydomain.com;

    port_in_redirect off;
    server_tokens off;
    autoindex off;

    client_max_body_size 15m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    access_log  /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/mydomian.com.log main;
    error_log   /usr/local/apps/nginx/var/log/mydomian.com.err;

    root   /home/www-data/public_html;
    index index.php  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc//html;
    }

    # Define default caching of 24h
    expires 86400s;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";

    # Redirect server error pages to static 50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc//html;
    }

    # Don't log robots.txt requests
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    # Rewrite for versioned CSS+JS via filemtime
    location ~* ^.+\.(css|js) {
        rewrite ^(.+)\.(\d+)\.(css|js)$ $1.$3 last;
        expires 31536000s;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }

    # Aggressive caching for static files
    # If you alter static files often, please use
    # add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    location ~* \.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|ogv|otf|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|t?gz|tif|tiff|ttf|wav|webm|wma|woff|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip)$ {
        expires 31536000s;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public";
    }

    location ~* (^(?!(?:(?!(php|inc)).)*/uploads/).*?(php)) {
        try_files $uri = 404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.socket;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
        include /usr/local/apps/nginx/etc/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }

}
```